# What to send someone to access my mysql database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database on my pc , what should i send someone to access it :S? A connection string or a live  link .Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[This worked perfectly](http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1269/12/how-to-grant-a-remote-access-to-a-single-mysql-database) for me. You're essentially giving them access to a separate installation of phpmyadmin that provides them access to any of the databases on your server via their separate database login credentials

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer available to others through the Internet, or does your ISP block access through port 80 (HTTP)? If the other person can access a web server on your computer that person could admin your mySQL database through phpMyAdmin?

If the other person knows how to use a terminal to perform sql-tasks I guess you could grant this person permission (see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html).